# How do I reformat a HD to GPT with the filesystem NTFS?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, gpt

I'm trying to install Windows on my hard drive. Unfortunately, it is in MBR and not GPT. After looking up this on the internet, I used a live USB of Ubuntu to gdisk it into being a GPT. I originally had Ubuntu in my hard drive. When I booted it up, it launched into grub rescue. I tried installing Windows again from a USB and it said "that it needed GPT partitions and NTFS filesystem." So, how do I do that? Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you boot from your USB pendrive, open a command prompt rather than start windows installation (usually via SHIFT + F10) and then do a diskpart, select disk X (make sure X is the right number!), clean. convert GPT.  Reboot, boot once more from the pendrive and install windows on your clean GPT disk (windows installer will create all the partitions you need, just keep defaults).

Comment: You should delete the partitions that exists on the disk, so the entire disk is unallocated, then boot to the Windows installer and allow it to create the partitions it needs.

Comment: What @Ramhound said is exactly what I did to do a clean install of Windows 10 on my formerly 7 SDD. I don't recall the exact details, but it was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Erase the drive using boot and nuke... http://www.dban.org/download

Comment: Thanks @Hennes for the answer. It helped a lot. Now it's working.

Comment: It is basically the same as Ramhound said. Wipe everything, then start again. Only this does not assume an already present OS (other than your windows installation DVD|pendrive) and you often connot fully wipe a disk if you are booted from it.  (I know, a few exceptions. E.g. FreeBSD after enabling 'shoot in foot' mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to install Windows on my hard drive. 
>   it said "that it needed GPT partitions and NTFS filesystem."

Which means you booted a modern windows in EFI mode. (which is a good thing). EFI mode need an EFI system partition on a GPT partitioned disk.

> Unfortunately, it is in MBR and not GPT.

Which can be solved in the folliowing ways:

- Ubuntu: Boot from any other disk (a live USB of Ubuntu will do fine) and wipe the whole disk.
- Windows: Boot from any other disk (the windows install DVD or pendrive will do) and wipe the whole disk. (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> should give you a command prompt from where you can launch diskpart. `select disk X` (make sure X is the right number!), `clean` (wipes the selected disk), `convert GPT` (create the GPT setup). Windows should be able to do this if you boot from a clean disk though, so this last step may be skipped)
- FreeBSD: Boot from any other disk or "set shoot in foot mode" with help of `sysctl kern.geom.debugflags=16`.

Next, reboot. This will be a clean boot with no old and potentially cached MBR information. Thew windows setup disk should create all the partitions which is needs. Mostly this is just clicking 'next next next' or 'ok, ok, ok'.

I suspect that you problems originated from thrying to wipe a disk which you were booted from. Usually this is a very bad idea and it can leave the system in an unworkable state. For this reason safeguards are applied.  But in this case you wanted to nuke the old installation and replace it with a new one and even though you used gpart on Ubuntu now is a good time to yell 'damn you clippy!' :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the hard drive and plugged it into my working PC - with a usb to 2.5 sata adapter.

Start > Run > cmd > right click "As Administrator" ...

diskpart (enter)... list disk (enter) ... select disk #__ (Verify you have the right one! Look at the size and MAKE SURE you have the right DISK!) ... (enter) ... clean (enter) ... create part pri (enter) ... select part 1 (enter) ... format fs=ntfs quick
Put the hard drive back into the original PC and was able to successfully install Windows 10

Answer (score -2):

if you don’t need anything on the hard disk, simply remove everything from it. For Windows to install, it needs either a GPT partitioned disk or an empty disk. An empty disk is easier to create: simply use the disk editor of your choice and overwrite sector 0 with all zeroes (make sure you select the correct disk!)

Comment: Not just sector 0... GPT has two locations. (Main & backup).

Comment: If it is already GPT, then the original poster has no need to remove GPT. Also, removing sector 0 with the MBR 0xEE-Partition "GPT Protective" at least for Windows makes the GPT inactive as well.